# Can't manage to get Datatables JQuery to work with Flask web app

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I am trying to make my manage my table to able to sort them by name, status, and so on.

Here what I tried to do.

Here is the link I followed https://datatables.net/manual/installation

**base.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );</script>

  </head>

  <body>
{% block nav %}{% endblock %}
```

**index.html**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% from "show_links.html" import show_links %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block nav%}
          {{ show_links(current_user) }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Current Tickets</h1>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table id="example" class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Tickets</th>
                  <th scope="col">Created</th>
                  <th scope="col">Project</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th scope="col">Priority</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for ticket in tickets %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ ticket.id }}</th>
                    <td><a href="{{ url_for ('ticket', ticket_id = ticket.id ) }}">{{ticket.title}}</a></td>
                      <td>{{ ticket.date_posted }}</td>
                      <td>{{ ticket.project_id }}</td>
                      <td>{{ ticket.status }}</td>
                     <td>{{ ticket.priority }}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ url_for ('ticket', ticket_id = ticket.id ) }}">Details</a></td>
                    {% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user['expert'] == 1 and ticket.status != 'Resolved'  %}
                    <td><a href="{{ url_for ('editTicket', ticket_id = ticket.id ) }}">Edit</a></td>
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
      </div>
       <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Current Projects</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          {% for project in projects %}
          <div class="list-group">
              <h4><a class="list-group-item-heading" href="{{ url_for ('project', project_id = project.id ) }}">{{ project.title }}</a></h4>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But there is still no change on my table. What am I doing wrong? how to integrate DataTables library properly so to be able to sort things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should load jquery before loading the datatables plugin. So the following lines should be in the inverse order like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks that partially solved my problem. However, it works only when there is no list of tickets (empty list of tickets at all) but when there is any ticket it doesn't get applied. So weird, do you have any idea why is that happening

Comment: hmmm... So, objects are rendered in template but are not formatted by datatables?? Strange... Try adding some fake rows outside the forloop and see if datatables works. Code looks pretty fine to me, that was the only issue I could notice...   Please confirm if 'tickets' are rendered in template even outside the table. I am more used to Django instead of Flask where by default I would do {% for object in object_list %}. Is 'tickets' a variable rendered in the template?

Comment: So the problem was i had more features than my column, so there was 8 features but i only specified 6 columns, i fixed that Thank you!!!

Comment: ohhh yes... careful with that... Glad I was able to help...!